# Aligning both rows and columns in a nested table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to process an XML file via XSLT to produce an HTML report. The report contains a table with 3 columns: Description, Date and Note. One row of this table may contain one description, but multiple dates and notes. The dates and notes for a single description form pairs, but sometimes either a date or a note is missing. I could have the following problems:

1. A note does not have a corresponding date, so the date-note pair representation is skewed (See Date 1.2 and Note 1.2 in the example). A desired representation would have an empty line followed by Date 1.2 on a different line.
2. A note spans multiple lines, but its corresponding date does not, so the following notes are not aligned with their dates.

Here is an example. I used `<br/>` elements for demonstration purposes.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="firstcolumn">Description</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td class="lastcolumn">Note</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="firstcolumn">Description 1. Could span multiple lines.</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">Date 1.2</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right" class="lastcolumn">Note without date 1.1<br/>  Note 1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="firstcolumn">Description 2.</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">Date 2.1<br/> Date 2.2</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right" class="lastcolumn">Some really long note<br/>spanning multiple lines 2.1<br/> Note 2.2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is a link to a fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNWqz/6/).

I tried to solve this with nested tables: for each row of the outer table, I created a nested table with 2 columns, each row of which contained a date-note pair (or an empty cell and a note). The dates and notes now align. However, the nested table column widths do not align across the rows of the outer table. I tried to solve this by setting all nested table widths using the styles

```
table { width:100%;table-layout:fixed;} /* for each nested table */
td {width:90px;} /* for the columns of nested tables */
```

The columns now align. However, sometimes the notes are cut off and not visible (using the overflow style I can make them appear outside the table border, but it looks ugly). Ideally, I would want to have column widths that adjust to the notes' lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made it!

What I did is:

- I broke the 2nd and 3rd rows in two
- to the first one I gave `rowspan="2"`
- I created two classes: `bt` and `bb`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}

td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

td.firstcolumn {
  width: 60%;
}

td.lastcolumn {
  width: 25%;
}

.bt {
  border-top: 0;
}

.bb {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="firstcolumn">Description</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td class="lastcolumn">Note</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="firstcolumn">Description 1. Could span multiple lines.</td>
    <td class="bb" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td class="bb" valign="top" align="right">Note without date 1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bt" valign="top" align="right">Date 1.2</td>
    <td class="bt" valign="top" align="right" class="lastcolumn"> Note 1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="firstcolumn">Description 2.</td>
    <td class="bb" valign="top" align="right">Date 2.1</td>
    <td class="bb" valign="top" align="right" class="lastcolumn">Some really long note<br/>spanning multiple lines 2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bt" valign="top" align="right"> Date 2.2</td>
    <td class="bt" valign="top" align="right" class="lastcolumn">Note 2.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNWqz/20/)**

Comment: thank you. Basically, I think you are suggesting to use rowspan attributes. I am thinking about it right now. I think it might be challenging to do in XSLT because I do not know how many date-note pairs I will have in advance. So, I do not know what the value of the rowspan attribute will be. I will give this another try and comment here.

Comment: I went with this approach, and it seems to work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to adjust width automatically based on contents try changing in example provided here
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_width

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="70%">January</td>
    <td width="30%">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>The width attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should of added this as a comment

Comment: then sorry, this is not the way to acquire reps.

Comment: @vinod Oh dear... it does indeed require 50 rep. We have all been there... this doesn't mean use an answer to post your comment. please do not do this is future.

Comment: @vinod Linking to another site is not an answer. Explaining what is wrong with the OP's code and giving a solution is an answer.

Comment: I did try setting nested table column width using either px or %. However, the column widths do not align across the rows of the outer table.